# How to create Add to cart button using Custom Module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, addtocart

I want to create Add to cart button using `Custom module` in product page,listing page and other page.Please advise me how to create this functionality.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Please try overriding this core file in your custom module/theme `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`